# Dependency that was created on its own (Foriegn key constraint)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-keys

In my MVC project I have used code first. I came across an issue while trying to delete an entry in the so called child class stating there was a conflict in the foreign key. But I have not created the foreign key column , but it has been generated as a result of the following line in the child class (`Views`) I suppose

```
 public virtual List<TC> TC {get;set;}
```

Now TC has an additional column `Views_ViewsID` which is a nullable property. I understansd that I should have used ViewModels to create a filter in the Action method rather than creating a property in the model class of `Views`.

Is there any way I can eliminate the dependency without creating a ViewModel as it will require to edit more than 3 action methods.

**What I am trying to achieve**

Be able to delete a row in `Views` without getting the constraint error

**What I tried**

When the delete of a particular row in `Views`is called, the rows in the `TC` where the value of `Views_ViewsID` equals `ViewsID` is taken and then set to null. But this doesn't help, as again the same error of foreign key constraint is thrown. I also tried to delete the column `Views_ViewsID` from the table `TC`, but it messes up the whole program.

**Inner exception**

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_dbo.TC_dbo.Views_Views_ViewsID1". The
>   conflict occurred in database "TedalsContext", table
>   "dbo.TC", column 'Views_ViewsID1'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

And i cannot find  a column named `Views_ViewsID1` in my table definition for `TC` ; it is named `Views_ViewsID` in table defintion.

**UPDATE based on comment**

I have two tables Views and TC both modelled as code first.

Views Model Class

```
public int ViewsID {get;set;}
/* Some other properties */

public virtual List<TC> TCList {get;set;} // This particular property was added just to be used as a filter in the View.
```

TC Model Class

```
public int TCID {get;set;}
/* Some other properties */

public int? Views_ViewsID {get;set;} // This was added to try what I have mentioned above in `What I have tried`
```

My table for TC also has the above structure with the column  `Views_ViewsID` included as a foreign key. I never added this in my model class until I came across the issue of deleting the `Views`.

So basically the column doesn't serve any purpose in my code. Just because I have the navigation property in the `Views model class` I suppose this column was added on its own.

Now when I try to delete any Views, even when there are no corresponding entries in the table `TC` , the delete throws the above mentioned exception.

**Code for setting the foreign key null in delete action method**

```
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Views views = db.Views.Find(id);
        var tc = db.TC.Where(x => x.Views_ViewsID == id).ToList();
        foreach(var t in tc)
        {
            t.Views_ViewsID = null;
            db.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
            //db.SaveChanges();
        }
        db.Views.Remove(views);
        db.SaveChanges(); // This line throws the exception
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty confused by the question.  Can you provide a minimal code example to explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Coulton: yes sure.. but to get a minimal code to reproduce the same effect is difficult i believe. Because the issue is with the database tables. But i can try for a better explanation

Comment: Cool, I'll look forward to seeing the update

Comment: @Coulton : Hope now the question explains the issue better.

Comment: Because model TC references the `ViewsID`, it has a foreign key.  It makes perfect sense for it to have a foreign key, because without a matching `View` the contents of `Views_ViewsID` is meaningless.  If you want to delete a `View` record that has it's `ViewID` referenced by a TC record, the TC records need removing or their `Views_ViewsID` value setting to null.

Comment: I have already set it to null; even in that case the exception is being thrown. I will also add the code how I set to null. And also there are Views which do not reference any `TC`. AFAIK, this is what happens: While creating a new instance of a View, if only one `TC` was selected to apply the filter, the corresponding TC gets a reference to the created `View`, if more than one `TC` filter was applied no reference is added to the `TC`.

Answer (score 0):

The number on

```
Views_ViewsID1
```

strongly suggests you have a problem with how you're setting the EF relationships.

This is often seen when you're manually setting a relationship via annotations or fluent but only attaching it to one end. The navigation property on the other end automatically creates a relationship for it to attach to.

You need to either completely define the relationship, or remove your attempt at doing so. Either way should fix the relationship to remove the duplicate key.

Comment: So is there any way I can bypass the navigation property and delete the Views entry? But I cannot find  how the value for `Views_ViewsID` is stored into my already existing `TC` table.

Comment: Without fixing the relationships you've defined? I'm not sure, it may have set it as HasOne not HasOptional. Look at the code from the migration that added the ViewID1 field.

Comment: i do not have any code in the migrations as I used code first migrations.

Comment: Code first generates migration classes with the Up and Down methods?

Comment: it doesnt have anything dealing with TC. it only has code relating to another table in the database which is irrelevant in the current context.

Comment: At some point a migration was created and used to update the database which added the foreign key relationship you are violating. Otherwise that relationship would not exist. If you find that migration you can see if it's the correct relationship. Unless you are Database first?

Comment: I cannot find the said migration. I am using Code first.. Are there any other way that I could override the delete function without deleting the TC property?